# How to use sscanf with argv

Tags: c, printf

I want to get input from the command line, (n) but my code is only writing this progress bar. I can't figure out how to get it to print a statement like `Enter a value` and then take that value and run the program with it. I have tried putting it so many different places. Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //Check command line
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: progress n\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    time_t c = atoi(argv[1]);
    int go = atoi(argv[1]);

    if (argc == 2) {
        //sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &n);
        time(&c);
        n = 10;
        go = n + c;

        char display[70];
        char equals[70];
        char disp[70];

        for (int i = 0; i <= go * n; i++) {
            strcpy(display, "progress: |");
            strcat(equals, "=");
            strcpy(disp, "|");

            char number[70];
            char space[70];

            sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &n);
            sprintf(number, "  %d%%", i * 2);
            sprintf(space, "%-52s", equals); // this keeps the 2nd bar static
            strcat(display, space);

            strcat(display, disp);
            strcat(display, number);
            //This is the final output
            fprintf(stderr, "\r%s %d  \r%s", equals, i, display);

            usleep(1000000);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you enter three arguments separated by a space, they will be presented as `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` and `argv[3]` not all as one argument.

Comment: this line: `printf("Usage: progress n\n");`  would be much better written as: `fprintf( stderr, "Usage: %s n\n", argv[0]);`

Comment: this line: `time_t c = atoi(argv[1]);` is placing trash into the variable `c`.  That trash is overlayed a few statements later with the statement: `time(c);`

Comment: this line `int go = atoi(argv[1]);` will execute, but is being overlayed a few statements later by: `go = n + c;`  so there is no need to initialize it to any set value.

Comment: this line: `int n = atoi(argv[1]);` will execute, but is being overlayed a few statements later by: `n = 10;` so there is no need to initialize it to any set value.

Comment: this line: `sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &n);`  keeps overlaying `n` with the same value as it was originally set, I.E. it also overlays the `10` that originally overlayed the initialization value.   A `time` value is VERY LARGE number. so the `for()` loop will loop a VERY LARGE number +10 iterations.  (actually a VERY LARGE number * the converted value from argv[1])

Comment: go is an integer (32 bit signed number)  but `time_t` is an unsigned int (usually a 32 bit number BUT modern systems are thinking about the end point of most RTC clock values so are making it a 64bit number.) .  Since the value returned from time is already past the 2gig value, using it with a `int` value will result in a negative value, even after adding what ever `n` is set to.   So the `for()` may iterate from 0 to some massive number of times,, just depending on how the compiler is handling the resulting overflows and variable signs.   Suggest using a debugger and stepping through the code

Answer (score 3):

To convert a command line argument string `argv[1]` representing a number to an `int n`, you can use any of these:

- `n = atoi(argv[1]);`  This one is simple for numbers in base 10.
- `n = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);`  This one can be used to parse suffixes or check if the argument is really a number.  It can support other bases or octal and hexadecimal syntax.
- `n = 0; sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &n);`  This method can be used too, but `n` must be initialized or `sscanf` return value must be checked to avoid undefined behavior for non numeric string arguments.

These methods have subtile differences in how they handle non numeric values and out of range values.

You can use `atoi()` for your purpose.

If your program is supposed to take 3 command line arguments, you must pass them on the command line.  To run the program, open a `CMD.EXE` terminal on `Windows` or a terminal window on `linux`, change the current directory to that of your executable and type:

```
C:\Project\Myproject> Myproject 123 456 789
```

Or on linux or Mac/OS:

```
user@mylaptop:~/projects/myproject > ./myproject 123 456 789
```

At the start of the `main` function, check the minimum number of command line arguments:

```
 if (argc < 3 + 2) {
     printf("missing arguments: expected n c and go\n");
     return 1;
 }
```

And convert each argument into the corresponding variables:

```
 int n = atoi(argv[1]);    // first argument is the value of n
 time_t c = atoi(argv[2]); // second argument is the value of c
 int go = atoi(argv[3]);   // third argument is the value of go
```